# "What's your position on the Phillips vs. Robertson controversy? – Chris Cudmore "

Tags: discussion

OK- I was not entirely sure what you meant by this Chris when you asked this comment.

It seems many people up voted the comment.

Where you talking about the DIY Picture with the screwdriver head thing? Or am I complelty out of the loop on this? :)

Comment: I think he's just comparing the benefits of various screw head types. Whenever someone says Robertson in the chatroom, Chris appears, so it's a bit of a running joke.